# Determine the value, when defined

Tags: limits, analysis

Determine the value, when defined, of $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1}{x^2-\lfloor x\rfloor}$$ where $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the greatest integer.

I know $\lim_{x\to\infty} {\lfloor x\rfloor} = \infty$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty} x^2$=$\infty$ but how do I combine them in order to get $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1}{x^2-[x]}$$

Comment: What do you mean by $[x]$?

Comment: $\lim_{x\to\infty} \lfloor x\rfloor =\infty,$ not $-\infty.$

Comment: copper.hat greatest integer

Answer (score 3):

Notice that $ x-1 \leq [x]\leq x$ so:

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{1}{x^2-x+1}\leq\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{1}{x^2-[x]}\leq \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{1}{x^2-x}$$

So:

$$0\leq\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{1}{x^2-[x]}\leq 0$$

And:
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{1}{x^2-[x]}=0$$

:)

Answer (score 1):

We always have $\lfloor x\rfloor\le x$.
For $x \ge 2$ we have ${x^2 \over 2} \ge x$.

Hence, if $x \ge 2$, we have  $x^2-\lfloor x\rfloor \ge x^2 -x \ge {x^2 \over 2}$ and
so
${1 \over x^2-\lfloor x\rfloor} \le {2 \over x^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Is in not obvious that $x^2$ grows proportionally faster than $[x]$ so $x^2 - [x]\to \infty$?

To verify:

$x \ge [x] > 0$ so $x^2 \ge [x]^2$ and $\frac 1 {x^2 - [x]} \le \frac 1{[x]^2 - [x]} = \frac 1{[x]([x] - 1)}< \frac 1{([x]-1)^2}\to 0$.

To formalize:

If $\epsilon > 0$ and we want $[x]- 1 > \sqrt{\frac 1\epsilon}$, which we can get if we choose $x > \lceil \sqrt{\frac 1\epsilon} \rceil + 1=N$.

Now if $x > N =\lceil \sqrt{\frac 1\epsilon} \rceil + 1$ then $[x] \ge \lceil \sqrt{\frac 1\epsilon} \rceil + 1 \ge  \sqrt{\frac 1\epsilon} + 1$

$[x]- 1 \ge \sqrt{\frac 1 \epsilon}$

$x^2 - [x]>[x]^2 - [x]=[x]([x]- 1)>([x]-1)^2 \ge \frac 1\epsilon$

$\frac 1{x^2 -[x]}  < \epsilon$.

So $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} \frac 1{x^2 -[x]} = \infty$.